# How to open Maps application from a Metro style app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

When a user clicks an address in my Metro style application, I would like to open the Maps application that comes with Windows 8 to show the address on the map.

I know you can't start processes directly due to sandboxing, but it is possible to start eg. a browser by using the [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx) class. Is there any similar way to start the Maps application with a specified address?

It would of course be possible to integrate the map into my application using the [Bing Maps for Metro Style Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846481.aspx), but I would rather not go there if an easier way exists.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx) the documentation for "URI Scheme for maps application".  Samples:

```
bingmaps: /* Opens the Maps app centered over the user’s region */

bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076 /* Opens the Map app centered over New York City */

bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076&lvl=10 /* Opens the Maps app centered over NYC at zoom level 10 */

bingmaps:?bb=39.719_-74.52~41.71_-73.5 /* Opens the map over NYC using the bounding box of the screen */
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 Maps App supports [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx), so the scenario you mentioned is supported. The URI definition hasn't been published yet. I'll post a link when it's available on dev.windows.com.

Answer (score 0):

Please find more details on my article: http://dreamteam-mobile.com/blog/2012/06/launch-maps-application-in-windows-8-csharp/

Summary, install Nuget Windows8.MapsHelper

```
Install-Package Windows8.MapsHelper
```

and then use following code:

```
MapsHelper.OpenMaps(lat: latitude, lon: longitude);
```